# Prove operator convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

I have to proove that given $X$ a normed space and $Y$ a Banach space, if the sequence of bounden linear operators from $X$ to $Y$ $\{A_n\} \rightarrow A$ and the sequence $\{x_n\} \rightarrow x$ then $A_n x_n \rightarrow Ax$ in $Y$.

So, showing that $||A_n x_n -Ax|| \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ is enough, but I don´t know where to apply the convergence of $x_n$, I also don´t know if I should use the definition of operator norm $||A||= min\{c\ge 0 : ||Av|| \le c||v||\}$

I tried to write the norm as $||A_n x_n - Ax||= ||A_n (x_n -x +x)-A(x)||$ and that doesn´t seem to take me anywhere.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your attempt does take you somewhere: $||A_n(x_n - x + x) - A(x)|| \leq ||A_n(x_n - x)|| + ||(A_n-A)(x)||$.

Comment: Ok, so now do I have $x_n \rightarrow x \Rightarrow ||A_n (x_n-x)|| \rightarrow 0$ and $A_n \rightarrow A \Rightarrow ||(An -A)(x)|| \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Yes, apply triangle inequality in the first, definition of operator norm in the second term.